# Stroustrup's guidelines for passing arguments in functions

Tags: c++, c++11

These are the guidelines Stroustrup gives in his newest C++ book
for passing arguments in functions:

```
[1] Use pass-by-value for small objects.
[2] Use pass-by-const-reference to pass large values that you don’t need to modify.
[3] Return a result as a return value rather than modifying an object through an argument.
[4] Use rvalue references to implement move (§3.3.2, §17.5.2) and forwarding (§23.5.2.1).
[5] Pass a pointer if ‘‘no object’’ is a valid alternative (and represent ‘‘no object’’ by nullptr).
[6] Use pass-by-reference only if you have to.
```

My questions:

1) He does not explain what he means by "small objects" in [1]. That rule is for built-in
types, but I am not sure about user-defined types. How "small" does a user-defined
type have to be in order to be passed as rule [1]?

2) I consider rule [3] to be only a matter of style. Am I wrong?

3) I wonder why rule [6]. Why does Stroustrup hate reference arguments? :) (just kidding)

Thank you

Comment: 1) there isn't a "hard limit"; my general rule of thumb is things > 128 bytes aren't "small" anymore. 2) It allows certain optimizations to be done, so it's a bit more than just style. 3) The less side effects your code has, the "cleaner" it is, usually. Note that these are guidelines, not hard-and-fast rules.

Comment: @Cornstalks 1) Why not just pass always by const reference? And pass by value only the simple built-in types. 3) Aha I see now. I was using Haskell years ago and I do realize what you say, thanks.

Comment: @user3111311: "Why not just pass always by const reference?" Because that's less efficient for small types - not just built-in types, but also small, simple-to-copy class types (for some context-dependent value of "small").

Comment: @MikeSeymour Do you use the size limit as Cornstalks said above, >128 bytes? What is typically small for you?

Comment: @user3111311: I use a soft limit of "a few words", and measure performance if it's important.

Comment: @MikeSeymour yes but for big projects you have to decide from the start. You can't make changes all over the project and then measure performance.

Comment: @user3111311: Even in the largest project, the amount of truly speed-critical code will be small, and will need careful measurement and optimisation however thoroughly you design it up-front. The most important design decision is how to isolate that code so that you can easily change it without affecting everything else. For the non-critical code, use your judgement to give a balance between readability and reasonable efficiency.

Comment: Strongly disagree with this question being closed as "opinion-based". These guidelines exist for technical reasons, and the question is asking for clarification of those reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of small that is small will vary by context.  Note that rule (1) is just an override for rule (2) -- pass by value *instead* of by `const&` if your object is small *and* you do not want to modify it.  Note that the size of an object, in this context, has more to do with the cost of copying it, and less to do with `sizeof`.  A 1 byte object that copies megabytes of data when it is copied is not a small object.

Returning instead of modifying can be strictly more efficient than modifying by reference.  Various elision mechanism (including NRVO and RVO) can result in things being directly constructed.  Your code also can avoid checking for non-empty state in the input parameters and clearing them.

Rule 4 and 1 can interact: if you are going to "take a copy" of what you pass in, even if the object is large, you should often do the copy in the argument list instead of in the body of the function.  This is nearly as efficient as doing multiple perfect overloads (it has 1 additional move in the worst case) so long as your `move` operation is efficient.